# Returning issue from jsonObject method when data has been saved in Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

There are two methods here. The first one has jsonData. Second one is responsible for making jsonObject.
postsFromJSONData calls the postsFromJsonObject 
When data has not saved in Core data, not problem happens.
The problem is when we fetch from the Core data and that has been saved. 
 Then, that fetched record is returned.
In point2 (it is marked in code) I printed post.title and it had value.
But in point1, when I returned the post.title which was returned from postsFromJsonObject, it was empty!

```
    static func postsFromJSONData(data: NSData, inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> PostResult {
        do {
            ...
            var finalPosts = [Post]()
            for postJSON in jsonDictionary1 {
                if let post = postFromJSONObject(postJSON, inContext: context) {
                    finalPosts.append(post)
                    print(post.title)
                    // Point1 ***********************************
                    print(finalPosts[0].title) // It prints an empty string.
                }
            }

            return .Success(finalPosts)
        } catch let error {
            return .Failure(error)

        }
    }
```

postFromJsonObject method:

```
private static func postFromJSONObject(json: [String:AnyObject], inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Post? {
        guard let
            ...
            postTitle = json["title"] as? String,
            postBody = json["body"] as? String else {
                return nil
        }
        var post: Post!
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Post")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", "\(postID)")
        do {
            let foundRecordsArray = try! mainQueueContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Post]
            print(foundRecordsArray.count)

            if foundRecordsArray.count > 0 {
                print("it is in coreData")
                post = foundRecordsArray.first!
                post.title = postTitle

            } else{
                print("It is new")
                context.performBlockAndWait() {
                    post = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Post", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Post
                    post.title = postTitle
                    ...
                }
            }

        } catch {
            print("error in post from jsonObject!")
        }

        // Point2 ************************************************
        print(post.title) // it prints the title correctly.
        return post
    }
```

In point2:
before returning the post I printed them.
WHEN IT WAS NOT IN CORE DATA:

> (entity: Post; id:
>   0xd000000001040002
>   x-coredata://D01327F6-B7A8-45E0-A728-2A13985BA8D6/Post/p65 ; data: {
>   body = "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et
>   cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem
>   sunt rem eveniet architecto";  id = 1;  title = "sunt aut facere
>   repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit";  userId =
>   1;  })

WHEN IT WAS IN CORE DATA

> (entity: Post; id: 0x7fc363d1fc30
>   x-coredata:///Post/t25999BB8-1F6A-4C4D-B217-3CAB2C8E50722 ; data: { 
>   body = "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et
>   cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem
>   sunt rem eveniet architecto";  id = 1;  title = "sunt aut facere
>   repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit";  userId =
>   1;  })

The different is the below lines:

> x-coredata:///Post/t25999BB8-1F6A-4C4D-B217-3CAB2C8E50722 
>   x-coredata://D01327F6-B7A8-45E0-A728-2A13985BA8D6/Post/p65

It might have made the problem!

---

I should also mention that when I moved postFromJSONObject code to the postFromJSONData the problem fixed so I think that the problem is from the point I return a post!